# Final Stand: Does the hover tank set off enemy mines?

Tags: battlefield-4

The Final Stand DLC for Battlefield 4 has introduced a hover tank. Does it set off enemy mines?

If such a thing existed in real life I would expect that the force of the thrusters keeping it off the ground would set off the mines. I'm not sure how the game determines when the mine should be detonated, though. Since the hover tank never "touches" the mine it might not set it off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes and no.

If using a M2 SLAM mine, then yes the hover tank will trigger detonation, as the M2 mines are triggered by proximity to the mine and not by actually driving over them.

However the M15 AT mines have no effect on the hover tank because, like you said, the hover tank never actually "touches" them.

Comment: I figured the SLAMs would still detonate but wasn't sure about the regular mines. I tried driving over what I thought were enemy AT mines in a hover tank last night and they didn't seem to detonate. I'm not completely sure that they were enemy mines in the heat of battle, though (they might have been friendly).